# How to encode custom HTTP headers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, http

Is there a class similar to HttpUtility to encode the content of a custom header? Ideally I would like to keep the content readable.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [HttpEncoder.HeaderNameValueEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.headernamevalueencode) in the .NET Framework 4.0 and above.

For previous versions of the .NET Framework, you can roll your own encoder, using the logic noted on the HttpEncoder.HeaderNameValueEncode reference page:

- All characters whose Unicode value is less than ASCII character 32,
  except ASCII character 9, are URL-encoded into a format of %NN where
  the N characters represent hexadecimal values.
- ASCII character 9 (the horizontal tab character) is not URL-encoded.
- ASCII character 127 is encoded as %7F.
- All other characters are not encoded.

Update:

As OliverBock point out the HttpEncoder.HeaderNameValueEncode Method is protected and internal. I went to open source Mono project and found the mono's implementation

```
void HeaderNameValueEncode (string headerName, string headerValue, out string encodedHeaderName, out string encodedHeaderValue)
{
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (headerName))
                encodedHeaderName = headerName;
        else
                encodedHeaderName = EncodeHeaderString (headerName);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (headerValue))
                encodedHeaderValue = headerValue;
        else
                encodedHeaderValue = EncodeHeaderString (headerValue);
}

static void StringBuilderAppend (string s, ref StringBuilder sb)
{
        if (sb == null)
                sb = new StringBuilder (s);
        else
                sb.Append (s);
}

static string EncodeHeaderString (string input)
{
        StringBuilder sb = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
                char ch = input [i];

                if ((ch < 32 && ch != 9) || ch == 127)
                        StringBuilderAppend (String.Format ("%{0:x2}", (int)ch), ref sb);
        }

        if (sb != null)
                return sb.ToString ();

        return input;
}
```

Just FYI

[here ] (https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Util/HttpEncoder.cs)

Comment: Sadly neither this version nor the .NET version (seen via Reflector) bother to properly encode '%' characters already in the data.

Comment: Is it me, or does `EncodeHeaderString` return a string containing only characters that are to be encoded, and doesn't include anything part of `input` that isn't less than 32, but not 9, and 127 (ASCII).

Comment: @GCymbala - Yes I agree. The inner loop appears to be missing an `else StringBuilderAppend(ch, ref sb);`. I do not see how the current "encoded" result would have any possible use.

Answer (score 7):

For me helped Uri.EscapeDataString(headervalue)

Answer (score 0):

This does the same job as HeaderNameValueEncode(), but will also encode % characters so the header can be reliably decoded later.

```
static string EncodeHeaderValue(string value)
{
    return Regex.Replace(value, @"[\u0000-\u0008\u000a-\u001f%\u007f]", (m) => "%"+((int)m.Value[0]).ToString("x2"));
}

static string DecodeHeaderValue(string encoded)
{
    return Regex.Replace(encoded, @"%([0-9a-f]{2})", (m) => new String((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16), 1), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: This doens't seem right. Shouldn't it be encoding things that AREN'T in that range? If I reverse the regex and encode this `£a£a£a` I end up with `%a3%61%a3%61%a3%61` which isn't ideal because I'd prefer the `a` not be encoded at all

Answer (score -2):

Mayeb This one ?
[UrlEncode Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

Comment: I am looking for a method that does not perform the encoding required for the URL but just considers the specific limitatons of the HTTP headers

Answer (score -4):

sorry its off the top of my head but for your request object there should be a headers object you can add to.

i.e. request.headers.add("blah");

Thats not spot on but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: The question is about encoding the header value, not about adding a header.