# Add special characters to HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader()

Tags: internet-explorer, c#-4.0, httpresponse

I want to generate PDF file with special characters.

My code is as follows:

```
 MemoryStream memoryStream = // get memory stream relevant to pdf file
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32;               
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", downloadLink));
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = @"application/pdf";
 HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

this works fine with normal characters for `downloadLink`. but for special characters such as `ABC_50_Română` then download file contain name as `ABC_50_RomÃ¢nÄƒ` with unrecognized characters.

I tried with using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF32`; and `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` for `ContentEncoding` . but unable to resolve the problem.

**EDIT:**
This problem occurs only in **internet explorer**

Comment: Not just IE - per [RFC 5987](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987) only ASCII characters are allowed in headers. Each browser can use its own workarounds though to recover uexpected data. Try to URL-encode the filename before sending it.

Comment: This has been asked before - [How to encode custom HTTP Headers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769080/how-to-encode-custom-http-headers-in-c-sharp). The answers propose various ways to achieve server-specific encoding, as the BCL's [header encoding function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.headernamevalueencode)  is ... internal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by convert the FileName to UTF8 before calling Response.AppendHeader

```
        if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).StartsWith("IE")) || (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).StartsWith("INTERNETEXPLORER")))
            downloadLink = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(downloadLink, UTF8Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", " ");
```

Good article found in [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/06/07/content-disposition-attachment-and-international-unicode-characters.aspx)